# Errors when including Cocoa header

Tags: c++, macos, cocoa, objective-c++, foundation

I've been creating a UI toolkit to use on MacOS and Windows, but im currently working and testing the MacOS side of things. Recently, when im compiling my code, using CMake, I get an unreasonable amount of errors from including the Cocoa header. [Here](https://ghostbin.com/paste/x3xes) is a ghostbin of the errors.

Comment: Your ghostbin link seems to be dead. I'm also getting a lot of errors, `unqualified-id`, `unknown type name`, etc. and I think it's because I have two libraries which import Cocoa/Foundation headers in the same project. Maybe. Hard to tell because there aren't a lot of posts on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is a complete answer to your question, but hopefully it gives you a path forward. Thanks to @uliwitness for mentioning `#if __OBJC__`.

So QT5 has a git repo for qmacextras, which combines c++ and objective-c, something I am doing and how I was seeing a bunch of errors when importing `<Foundation/Foundation.h>` or `<Cocoa/Cocoa.h>`. Looking at some of their code, I saw this:

```
// ### remove when merged to QtCore
/*!
 * \macro Q_FORWARD_DECLARE_OBJC_CLASS(classname)
 *
 * Forward-declares an Objective-C class name in a manner such that it can be
 * compiled as either Objective-C or C++.
 *
 * This is primarily intended for use in header files that may be included by
 * both Objective-C and C++ source files.
 */
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define Q_FORWARD_DECLARE_OBJC_CLASS(classname) @class classname
#else
#define Q_FORWARD_DECLARE_OBJC_CLASS(classname) typedef struct objc_object classname
#endif
```

and

```
// Put in your header file
Q_FORWARD_DECLARE_OBJC_CLASS(NSData);
Q_FORWARD_DECLARE_OBJC_CLASS(NSImage);
// etc
```

https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtmacextras.git/tree/examples/macextras/macfunctions?h=5.14

Using this might negate those errors.

Answer (score 0):

You're not really asking a question... but from a casual glance at what little information you provide, it looks like there is ObjC code being run through a non-ObjC compiler.

This usually happens when someone includes an ObjC header from a C or C++ source file. A very common way of causing this is to add a precompiled header to your project that includes Cocoa/Cocoa.h. A precompiled header is used for *all* C-descended languages you compile, so also for C or C++ files.

To avoid ObjC-specific code from being included in non-ObjC files, wrap it in `#if __OBJC__` preprocessor macros. (This also applies to C++ code in your precompiled header, which you'll want to wrap in `#if __cplusplus`)